# How can I add an option to a foreach loop selectbox sorted by name?

Tags: php, html, select, foreach

I have a loop of options in my select box. They are ordered by name:

```
 <select>
    <?php
      $pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY name ASC;');
      while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<option>".$row['name']."<option>
       }
   ?>
 </select>
```

The result looks for example like this:

```html
<select>
<option>Alfred</option>
<option>Berta</option>
<option>Jane</option>
<option>Victor</option>
</select>
```

I want now to add another option manually to the select box:

```
<option>Tamara</option>
```

But it should also be sorted, so my result will be:

```html
<select>
<option>Alfred</option>
<option>Berta</option>
<option>Jane</option>
<option>Tamara</option>
<option>Victor</option>
</select>
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to build your own array and use [`natcasesort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php) because it sorts better than the standard `sort()`. [Sorting arrays comparison chart](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

```
<select>
<?php
// A listing of names you wish to manually add
$names = [ 'Tamara', 'Jack' ];

// Add names from the database
$pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY name ASC;');
while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $names[] = $row['name'];
}

// Perform a proper sort
natcasesort( $names );

// Loop and output
foreach( $names as $name )
{
    echo '<option>'.$name.'</option>';
} 
?>
</select>
```

---

**Update per the comments**

You will need the power of [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#example-5983)

```
<select>
<?php
// A listing of rows you wish to manually add
// Since these are not from the database, we need to manually assign the "columns" to be used later
$rows = [
    [ 'name' => 'Tamara', 'id' => 'fake id', 'project' => 'whatever', 'group' => 'some group' ],
    [ 'name' => 'Jack', 'id' => 'fake id 2', 'project' => 'whatever 2', 'group' => 'some group 2' ]
];

// Add rows from the database
$pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY name ASC;');
while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}

// Perform a sort which targets the name
usort( $rows, function( $a, $b ){
    return strcmp( $a['name'], $b['name'] );
} );

// Loop and output
foreach( $rows as $data )
{
    echo '<option value='.$data['id'].' data-project='.$data['project'].' data-group='.$data['group'].'>'.$data['name'].'</option>';
} 
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! One question, my option in the loop has more values. Like this `<option value='.$row['id'].' data-project='$row['project']' data-group='$row['group']'>'.$row['name'].'</option>` Is this possible with your solution?

Comment: @Jarla Of course it is. I assume you want to know how?

Comment: I am working on it right now, how to do it. But still did not succeed :)

Comment: @Jarla check out the update. I haven't tested it but it should work

Comment: Ah ok, understand. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You have to [`sort()`](http://php.net/sort) using PHP :

```
<?php
    $data = [] ; // use an array to store your data.
    $pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY name ASC;');
    while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $data[] = $row['name'] ; // add into data
    }
    // add your value :
    $data[] = "Tamara" ;
    // then sort 
    sort($data);
?>
<select>
<?php
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        echo '<option>'.$item.'</option>' ;
    }
?>
</select>
```

Note that your `ORDER BY` is no longer necessary, in this case.